# Use of enable_if to match only classes which have a certain static data member, and that has only specific values

Tags: c++, templates, boost, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I want to specialize a function for a subset of classes which: have a certain static data member variable, and such variable has only certain possible values.

The code below illustrates the intent, but it does not compile unless I comment out the lines related to the `B` classes in `main`. This is because `code` is not a member of the `Bx` classes, but the `enable_if` condition is valid if the template argument has a `code` member variables. How should I modify it?

Unfortunately I work with very old compilers, hence no support for C++11: I compile with the option `-std=c++03`.

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/core/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/or.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/not.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/bool.hpp>
using std::cout;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::mpl;

template <int N> struct A1 { static const int code = N; };
template <int N> struct A2 { static const int code = N; };
// ... other classes with static data member 'code'
template <int N> struct AN { static const int code = N; };

struct B1{};
struct B2{};
// ... other classes potentially passd as argument to the foo function
struct BN{};

template <typename T>
struct Condition : or_<bool_<T::code == 1>, bool_<T::code == 2> > {};


template <typename T>
typename enable_if<not_<Condition<T> >, void>::type
   foo(const T& arg) { cout << "This class does not have a static member code or its value is not 1 or 2\n"; }

template <typename T>
typename enable_if<Condition<T>, void>::type
   foo(const T& arg) { cout << "This class has a static member code and its value is " << T::code << "\n"; }

int main()
{
    foo(A1<0>()); // this should match the 1st version of foo
    foo(A2<1>()); // this should match the 2nd version of foo
    foo(AN<2>()); // this should match the 2nd version of foo
    foo(B1());    // this should match the 1st version of foo
    foo(BN());    // this should match the 1st version of foo
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't your code work?

Comment: Because `code` is not a member of the `B` classes and It is used in the instantiation of `enable_if`. I have updated the question.

Comment: Can you use this? https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/tti/doc/html/the_type_traits_introspection_library/tti_detail_has_static_member_data.html

Comment: If you can't use C++11, I suppose you must write `foo(B1())`, not `foo(B1{})`

Comment: @max66, thanks, I updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is that you need a C++03 solution, so you can use SFINAE but not all language improvement that are available starting from C++11.

Anyway, I propose you a solution that is convoluted like yours (maybe more) but is completely boost free.

If you define a trivial bool wrapper (that can roughly substitute the C++11 `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`)

```
template <bool B>
struct bool_wrapper
 { static const bool value = B; };
```

you can define your condition as follows

```
template <typename, typename = bool_wrapper<true> >
struct cond : public bool_wrapper<false>
 { };

template <typename T>
struct cond<T, bool_wrapper<(1 == T::code) || (2 == T::code)> >
   : public bool_wrapper<true>
 { };
```

and if you define a `enable_if` type traits (the same as the C++11 `std::enable_if`)

```
template <bool, typename = void>
struct enable_if
 { };

template <typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T>
 { typedef T type; };
```

you can SFINAE enable/disable your `foo()` functions

```
template <typename T>
typename enable_if<false == cond<T>::value>::type foo (T const & arg)
 { std::cout << "no static member code or value not 1 and not 2\n"; }

template <typename T>
typename enable_if<true == cond<T>::value>::type foo (T const & arg)
 { std::cout << "static member code and its value is " << T::code << "\n"; }
```

The following is a full working C++98 example

```
#include <iostream>

template <int N> struct A1 { static const int code = N; };
template <int N> struct A2 { static const int code = N; };
// ... 
template <int N> struct AN { static const int code = N; };

struct B1{};
struct B2{};
// ...
struct BN{};

template <bool B>
struct bool_wrapper
 { static const bool value = B; };

template <typename, typename = bool_wrapper<true> >
struct cond : public bool_wrapper<false>
 { };

template <typename T>
struct cond<T, bool_wrapper<(1 == T::code) || (2 == T::code)> >
   : public bool_wrapper<true>
 { };

template <bool, typename = void>
struct enable_if
 { };

template <typename T>
struct enable_if<true, T>
 { typedef T type; };


template <typename T>
typename enable_if<false == cond<T>::value>::type foo (T const & arg)
 { std::cout << "no static member code or value not 1 and not 2\n"; }

template <typename T>
typename enable_if<true == cond<T>::value>::type foo (T const & arg)
 { std::cout << "static member code and its value is " << T::code << "\n"; }

int main ()
 {
   foo(A1<0>()); // match the 1st version of foo
   foo(A2<1>()); // match the 2nd version of foo
   foo(AN<2>()); // match the 2nd version of foo
   foo(B1());    // match the 1st version of foo
   foo(BN());    // match the 1st version of foo
 }
```

I don't know the boost classes your using but I suppose you can modify your code (to works almost as my no-boost solution) as follows

```
template <typename, typename = bool_<true> >
struct Condition : public bool_<false>
 { };

template <typename T>
struct Condition<T, bool_<(1 == T::code) || (2 == T::code)> >
   : public bool_<true>
 { };
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask

> I do not understand how it works for the case A1<0>. The specialization of Condition should be the preferred match, with the 2nd argument expanding to bool_. That class inherits from bool_, so, it should pick the wrong versions of foo. However it works. How is it possible?

Well... when you write `foo(A1<0>())`, the compiler must understand if `cond<A1<0>>::value` is `true` or `false` to enable the first version of `foo()` or the second one.

So the compiler must implement `cond<A1<0>>`. But there isn't a `cond` template class that receive only a typename. Anyway, the compiler find that

```
template <typename, typename = bool_wrapper<true> >
struct cond;
```

matches using the default value for the second template parameter.

There aren't alternative, so there isn't ambiguity, so `cond< A<1> >` become `cond< A<1>, bool_wrapper<true> >`

Now the compiler must choose between the main version of `cond<typename, typename>` (the one that inherit from `bool_wrapper<false>`) and the specialization (the one that inherit from `bool_wrapper<true>`).

`cond< A<1>, bool_wrapper<true> >` surely matches the main version, but matches also the specialization? If matches the also the specialization, the compiler must prefer the specialization.

So we need to see if `cond< A<0>, bool_wrapper<true> >` matches the specialization.

Using `A<0>` as `T`, we have that the specialization become

```
cond< A<0>, bool_wrapper<(1 == A<0>::code) || (2 == A<0>::code)> >
```

that is

```
cond< A<0>, bool_wrapper<(1 == 0) || (2 == 0)> >
```

that is

```
cond< A<0>, bool_wrapper<false || false> >
```

that is

```
cond< A<0>, bool_wrapper<false> >
```

and this doesn't matches `cond< A<0>, bool_wrapper<true> >`.

So `cond< A<0> >`, that is `cond< A<0>, bool_wrapper<true> >`, matches only the main version of `cond<typename, typename>`, so inherit from `bool_wrapper<false>`.

Now we can give a look at `cond< A<1> >`.

As for `cond< A<0> >`, the only template `cond` that matches `cond< A<1> >` is `cond<typename, typename>` with the second `typename` with the default value.

So `cond< A<1> >` is `cond< A<1>, bool_wrapper<true> >`.

But `cond< A<1>, bool_wrapper<true> >` matches only the main version of `cond<typename, typename>` or also the specialization?

We can see that using `A<1>` as `T`, we have that the specialization become

```
cond< A<1>, bool_wrapper<(1 == A<1>::code) || (2 == A<1>::code)> >
```

that is

```
cond< A<1>, bool_wrapper<(1 == 1) || (2 == 1)> >
```

that is

```
cond< A<1>, bool_wrapper<true || false> >
```

that is

```
cond< A<1>, bool_wrapper<true> >
```

and this matches `cond< A<1>, bool_wrapper<true> >`.

So, for `cond< A<1> >`, AKA `cond< A<1>, bool_wrapper<true>`, both versions of `cond<typename, typename>` match, so the compiler must choose the specialization, so `cond< A<1> >` inherit from `bool_wrapper<true>`.

Comment: This is nice. It avoids splitting the condition in 2 parts, as the existence of the static data member is checked implicitly. I do not understand how it works for the case `A1<0>`. The specialization of `Condition` should be the preferred match, with the 2nd argument expanding to `bool_<false>`. That class inherits from `bool_<true>`, so, it should pick the wrong versions of `foo`. However it works. How is it possible?

Comment: @Fabio - Answer improved. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I mark this one as correct as it works and it is more elegant than mine. Regarding my further question, I did not articulate properly, as there is not much space in comment. As a a result, I do not think the further explanation addresses it. So I opened a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52583833/role-of-default-template-arguments-in-the-context-of-partial-specialization. You may consider removing extra details from this answer and reply to that one.

Answer (score 1):

Based on J. Zwinck's suggestion, I got it to work.

Putting the two conditions in an `and_`template class does not work for the same reason as stated above. However, I can put the first condition (class has member variable `code`) in an `enable_if`, then the second condition (code has specific values) inside the class (see example below).

If is a bit convoluted though. If anybody can suggest a more elegant solution I will accept it.

```
#include <boost/tti/has_static_member_data.hpp>

BOOST_TTI_HAS_STATIC_MEMBER_DATA(code)

template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct Condition : false_type {};;

template <typename T>
struct Condition<T, typename enable_if<bool_<has_static_member_data_code<T,const int>::value> >::type>
{
    typedef or_<bool_<T::code == 1>, bool_<T::code == 2> > type;
    const static bool value = type::value;
};
```