# Role of default template arguments in the context of partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, partial-specialization

I am not clear about the interaction of default template arguments in the context of partial specialization, for choosing which is the better matching template. This questions stems from code posted in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52565407/use-of-enable-if-to-match-only-classes-which-have-a-certain-static-data-member) by max66.

Given the definitions of the classes `A` and `B`:

```
template <int N> struct A { static const int code = N; };

struct B{};
```

and the following template classes:

```
// primary template
template <typename, typename Enable = bool_constant<true>>
struct cond : public bool_constant<false> {};

// specialization
template <typename T>
struct cond<T, bool_constant<(0 == T::code)>> : public bool_constant<true> {};
```

1) `cond<B>::value` evaluates to `false` (i.e. the primary is chosen). This is clear as the primary template yields `cond<B, bool_constant<true>>`, the specialization fails, hence the primary template is the only possible choice.

2) `cond<A<0>>::value` evaluates to `true` (i.e. the specialization is chosen). This is clear as the primary template yields `cond<B, bool_constant<true>>`, the specialization also yields `cond<B, bool_constant<true>>`, hence the specialization is preferred because the argument for the 2nd template parameter is explicitly given.

3) `cond<A<1>>::value` evaluates to `false` (i.e. the primary is chosen). This is not clear to me. The primary template yields `cond<B, bool_constant<true>>`, the specialization  yields `cond<B, bool_constant<false>>`. Given the argument for the 2nd template parameter is explicitly given in the specialization, why is not preferred?

I suppose the behaviour in (3) is due to some interaction between the default template argument of the primary template and the specialization. In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18701381/5800661) Jerry Coffin states something which might explain this behaviour:

> if we change the specialization so that its specialization
>   is for a type other than the default provided by the base template
>   then the base template will be chosen.

Can somebody please elaborate on this rule? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename, typename Enable = bool_constant<true>>
struct cond : public bool_constant<false> {};
```

is identical to

```
template <typename, typename Enable = bool_constant<true>> struct cond;

template <typename, typename Enable>
struct cond : public bool_constant<false> {};
```

Later might be clearer to understand the result.

When you write `cond<C>`, thanks to default argument, it is equivalent to `cond<C, bool_constant<true>>`.

Then we try to match that to *"better instantiation"*.

We have the choice between:

```
// primary template
template <typename, typename Enable>
struct cond : public bool_constant<false> {};
```

and partial specialization, which use SFINAE:

```
// specialization
template <typename T>
struct cond<T, bool_constant<(0 == T::code)>> : public bool_constant<true> {};
```

If `0 == T::code` is ill formed, specialization is discarded and only primary template is a viable solution, so it is used.

Else if `0 == T::code` evaluates to `false`, the specialization doesn't match and primary template is also used.
Note that using  `cond<C, bool_constant<false>>` would use the specialization in that case.

Else, `0 == T::code` evaluates to `true`, and then both primary and specialization are viable, but specialization is more specialized, so it is chosen.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the case where `0 == T::code` evaluates to `false`? Why it does not match? Why using explicitly `cond<C, bool_constant<false>>` would instead match?

Comment: As I said, `cond<C>` is `cond<C, bool_constant<true>>` and `cond<C, bool_constant<true>>` doesn't match `cond<T, bool_constant<false>>` (`T` == `C` but `true` != `false`).

Comment: I am still confused. I can see it does not match. The question is, why should it match to be a valid specialization? My understanding of default template arguments is that, if one is not specifically provided, then the default is used. But if any valid type is explicitly provided, be it `bool_constant<false>` or `void` or whatever, that should succesfully replace the default value and therefore be preferred. Here we are saying that this will only happen if that matches the default. What is the precise rule?

Comment: First we fill missing arguments by default. so `cond<C>` -> `cond<C, bool_constant<true>>`. For the definition of primary template, it is a catch all, so any `cond<T, U>` can use that definition, but it is not necessary the more **specialized**. The SFINAE version is more specialized, so once correctly formed, it take precedence over the primary template (if it matches).

Comment: Ok, the last part of the last sentence is the answer I was looking for: "The SFINAE version is more specialized, so once correctly formed, it take precedence over the primary template (**if it matches**)". You may consider emphasizing this in your answer, as this was the culprit. Any reference I can read?

Comment: See [partial_specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization). (Especially *"Partial ordering"*).